# Usage of tf.device

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm defining a custom GRUcell and following is an abstact example.

The first code block defines the grucell and weight parameters are defined with the device('/cpu:0'):

```
class GRUCell(RNNCell):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, activation = tf.tanh, init_device = '/cpu:0', dtype = tf.float32, reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.activation = activation
        self.dtype = dtype

        with tf.variable_scope('grucell'):
            with tf.device(init_device):
                w = tf.get_variable('w', [self.input_size, self.hidden_size], self.dtype)
                b = ~~
```

The second code block includes some operation which utilizes the defined grucell

```
def build_model(some_arguments...):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
      ~~
      ~~
      cell_forward = GRUCell(some_other_arguments...)
```

What will happen if I run aforementioned code build_model?

And what if I don't designate the device of GRUCell as '/cpu:0' ?

Answer (score 0):

They will be placed on the device, specified by the closest scope upstream. GRU - on the GPU, everything else - on the CPU

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('cpu'):
  x = tf.zeros([1])
  y = tf.zeros([1])
  print(x, y)
  sm = x+y
  with tf.device('gpu'):
    z = tf.zeros([1])
    ml = sm*z


with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
  sess.run(ml)
```

Output:

```
add: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-06-13 07:14:36.132810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:1059] add: (Add)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2019-06-13 07:14:36.132821: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:1059] mul: (Mul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
zeros: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-06-13 07:14:36.132827: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:1059] zeros: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
zeros_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-06-13 07:14:36.132833: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:1059] zeros_1: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
zeros_2: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2019-06-13 07:14:36.132838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:1059] zeros_2: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

Comment: So the inner computation of GRU will be operated on cpu and there is no benefit to do like that. Is it right?

Comment: it is not quiet clear where inner operations of GRU will be placed, apart from weight initialization op and there might be some sence to do like you do. Try to look into https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/DeviceWrapper